# How do I alter the schema without destroying data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my current schema

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "historical_data": {
        "properties": {
          "continent": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "funding": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "year": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "agency": {
            "type": "string"
          },
            "misc": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "university": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I have 700k records uploaded. Without destroying the data, how can I make the university index not "not_analysed" such that the change reflects in my existing data?

Comment: Isn't it already not_analyzed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping for an existing field cannot be modified.
However you can achieve the desired outcome in two ways .

1. Create another field. Adding fields is free using [put _mapping API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/)

> ```
> curl -XPUT localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX/_mapping -d '{
>   "properties": {
>     "new_university": {
>       "type": "string"
>     }
>   }
> }'
> ```

2. Use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html), add a sub-field to your not_analyzed field.

> ```
> curl -XPUT localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX/_mapping -d '{
>     "properties": {
>         "university": {
>             "type": "string",
>             "index": "not_analyzed",
>             "fields": {
>                 "university_analyzed": {
>                     "type": "string" // <-- ANALYZED sub field
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }'
> ```

In both the case, you need to reindex in order to populate the new field. Use [_reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#_reindex_to_change_the_name_of_a_field)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_reindex -d '{
  "source": {
    "index": "YOUR_INDEX"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "YOUR_INDEX"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.university = ctx._source.university"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not exactly forced to "destroy" your data, what you can do is reindex your data as described in [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime) (I'm not gonna rip off the examples as they are particularly clear in the section Reindexing your data with zero downtime).

For reindexing, you can also take a look at the [reindexing API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html), the simplest way being:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
```

Of course it will take some resources to perform this operation, so I would suggest that you take a complete look at the changes you want to introduce in your mapping, and perform the operation when you have the least amount of activity on your servers (e.g. during the weekend, or at night...)